# How to assign event listeners to React.useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-listener

I need to scroll a div using a handle element. I wrapped the functionality in a hook. I created a ref for the handle element but it does not allow for assigning event listeners to it. I want to avoid using element inline event listeners, is that even possible?

```
import React from "react";

export default function useScrollOnDrag() {
    const refX = React.useRef(null);
    const refY = React.useRef(null);

    const [scrollState, setScrollState] = React.useState({
        isScrolling: false,
        clientX: 0,
        scrollX: 0,
        clientY: 0,
        scrollY: 0,
    });

    refX.current.onmousedown((e) => {
        setScrollState({ ...scrollState, isScrolling: true, clientX: e.clientX });
    });
    refX.current.onmousemp(() => {
        setScrollState({ ...scrollState, isScrolling: false });
    });

    refX.current.onmousemove((e) => {
        const { clientX, scrollX, isScrolling } = scrollState;
        if (isScrolling) {
            refX.current.parentElement.scrollLeft = scrollX + e.clientX - clientX;
            setScrollState({ ...scrollState, scrollX: scrollX + e.clientX - clientX, clientX: e.clientX });
        }
    });
    return [refX];
}
```

and then import the hook and use it like this:

```
const [scrollHandle] = useScrollOnDrag()
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2 ref={scrollHandle}>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
```

Running example: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-haze-lzfxm?file=/src/index.js

What I want to avoid is creating the listeners like this

```
     <div
        ref={ref}
        onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
        onMouseMove={onMouseMove}
      >
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should wrap the event listeners in `useEffect` and use `addEventListener` like:

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    refX.current.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
      setScrollState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        isScrolling: true,
        clientX: e.clientX
      }));
    });
  }, []);
```

Read more about mousedown event [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event). You can search for other events as well, I just wanted to point out the right direction.